# Downloading image from a url into a UIImageVIew dynamically

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to insert and image into a UIImageView from a url. I used the following code to do so.
When running the program gets stuck at

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
```

In the below code and it shows "Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT" on that particular line.
Can someone help me with this and tell if the format that i used is correct or what i had did wrong??

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newoffer";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
NSDictionary *temp = [product objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UILabel *Label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:201];
Label.text = [temp objectForKey:@"item_name"];
UIImageView *Image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
NSString *urlstring=[temp objectForKey:@"image_url"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
Image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

return cell;

}
```

Comment: If possible post your URL here

Comment: If still facing any problem post here else if my answer helps you then please mark my answer right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
Image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

To:

```
 dispatch_queue_t myqueue = dispatch_queue_create("myqueue", NULL);

    // execute a task on that queue asynchronously
    dispatch_async(myqueue, ^{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
Image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; //UI updates should be done on the main thread
     });
    });
```

As mentioned by others, an Image Caching library like SDWebImage will help a lot because even with this implementation, you just push the download process to a background thread so the UI does not get stucked,  but you are not caching anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
[image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.vbarter.com/images/content/1/9/19517.jpg"]]]];
```

For async downloading

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

[image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.vbarter.com/images/content/1/9/19517.jpg"]]]];

});
```

if url is dynamic then

```
NSString *stringUrl; // this can be any valid url as string

[image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl]]]];
```

Comment: @ Anand When i use the above code it works. But the URL is dynamical and it varies. So when i put the image into a NSString object then the above mentioned problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`

will load imageData synchronous, that means main thread will be blocked .

Use the project on github:[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for image asynchronous loading and cache.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably better libraries that do this now, but I have always been using this for my projects and it works well: [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView).  There are other alternatives like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

But basically, you don't want to use

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

because it will block the main thread until the image is downloaded. To avoid this you might want to use something asynchronous, like the above two libraries.

For example, with [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView), it becomes as easy as:

```
myImageView.imageURL = someNSURL;
```